# Activerecord - Get sum of all related record

Tags: activerecord, subquery

I have 2 models: Invoice and Payment

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: invoices
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  totale      :decimal(8, 3)
#  ....
#  ....
#

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :payments

end




# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: payments
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  invoice_id :integer
#  importo    :decimal(8, 3)
#  ....
#

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

end
```

I need to sum, in a invoice's view, the sum of all payment's importo, without iteration in each invoice.

How can i find it?
i tried with

```
@fatture = Invoice.all
@fatture.payment.sum(:importo)
```

without succes!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the problem, you want to sum the 'importo' of all payments associated to any invoice without iterating over the payment in ruby.

I believe what you need is a join of payments onto invoice.

```
Invoice.joins(:payments).sum('payments.importo')
```

[Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins)